# Windows Mobile 8 - Removing StackPanel which was created dynamically

Tags: windows-phone-8, stackpanel

I have created a StackPanel via C# codes and added it to the base panel through:

```
pnlBase.Children.Add(newStackPanel);
```

The base panel contains few controls like `TextBlock`, `TextBox`, `RadioButtons` etc. The `newStackPanel` I created via C# codes to appear on a button click on top of everything in the middle. When I finish entering data on `newStackPanel`, I want to dispose or remove it from base panel. Can you please guide me how to do it because it does not appear on:

```
pnlBase.Children.Remove(?????);
```

Please Help!!!

Comment: Keep a reference to the `StackPanel` you added, and when it's time to remove it, use that reference to pass to `Remove`. If that's not the solution, you'll need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
pnlBase.Children.Remove(newStackPanel as UIElement);
```

Comment: how could it work? I mentioned that i have created newStackPanel via c# codes at run-time! So, I have created a Stackpanel at run-time and want to remove/dispose/hide it during run-time!!!

Comment: @HaroonPatel-PK if you have created stack panel at run time and its instance is 'newStackPanel' then i dont see why this shouldnt not work.